# Как рассчитать вероятность?

Tags: теория-вероятностей

К примеру у нас есть данные типа: цвет | форма | еда

И допустим такой их набор: (красный, круглый, яблоко), (красный, вытянутый, перец), (зелёный, круглый, арбуз), (зелёный, вытянутый, яблоко), (красный, круглый, яблоко), (красный, круглый, помидор).

Первые два значения - параметры, последнее значение - класс.

Как правильно вычислить вероятность события к примеру P(красный * круглый), предполагая, что значения (подразумевающиеся как события) связаны?

По Вентцелю это вроде вычисляется так:

```
P(красный*круглый) = P(красный)*P(круглый|красный) или P(круглый)*P(красный|круглый)
```

Если вероятность P(красный) или P(круглый) я понимаю, как определить по данным, то условную вероятность нет. Условная вероятность, как я понимаю, показывает вероятность того, что событие произойдёт при условии, что произошло другое.

Тогда посчитать её можно будет для примера P(красный|круглый) посчитав все случаи, когда появлялось событие "красный" и события, когда при событии "красный" было и событие "круглый" и второе поделить на первое (моё предположение, в книге Вентцеля немного не понятно).

Прошу помочь, просто хочу понять этот момент.

Comment: Вот тут много задач про вероятность https://repetitor-mathematics.ru/teoriya-veroyatnosti-formulyi-i-primeryi-resheniya-zadach/ с разбором и решением с объяснением. Ваша задача похожа на задачу про лампочки, на мой взгляд.
В задаче тоже лампочки перегоревшие и не перегоревшие - класс лампочки, параметры перегорели/не перегорели, по аналогии с яблоко красный/круглый. И показано каким образом определить вероятность.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

P(красный)=4/6 (4 из 6)

P(круглый|красный)=3/4 (3 из 4)

P(круглый)=4/6 (4 из 6)

P(красный|круглый)=3/4 (3 из 4)

Comment: в варианте p(круглый|красный) (3 из 4) - чего 4 и чего 3?

Comment: 4 -- размер выборки (все красные). 3 -- размер хороших элементов выборки (все круглые)

Comment: 4 красных, из них 3 вместе с круглым